# double equals to 0 on 9999999 / 10000000

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a problem, im doing some personal research into how this works http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17480/Optimizing-integer-divisions-with-Multiply-Shift-i but i did not get far until i got stumped, so the code atm is supposed to return roughly 100% error

```
        double sum = 0, div = 3;
        DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
        List<double> l1 = new List<double>();
        for (int a = 0; a < 10000000; a++)
        {
            sum = a / div;
            l1.Add(sum);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Milisecond: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(t1).TotalMilliseconds);
        t1 = DateTime.Now;
        List<double> l2 = new List<double>();
        for (int a = 0; a < 10000000; a++)
        {
            sum = a * div;
            l2.Add(sum);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Milisecond: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(t1).TotalMilliseconds);
        int c=0;
        int err = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < (l1.Count < l2.Count ? l1.Count : l2.Count); a++)
        {
            c++;
            err += l1[a] != l2[a] ? 1:0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + 100*(err / c) + "%");
```

but that last line returns 0 apparently 9999999 / 10000000 = 0

any ideas to how i can work around the problem? my best guess is that its a float problem. (but now i know its a doh error on my part)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variables of the operation are declared as int and therefore the operation is done on integers and the result is only then converted to double.

To get the double result, you could do:

```
dRes = (double)x / y;
```

By the way, there is a better way to test the running time of code:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// ... Some code

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Stopwatch never heard of it, but i tried it out and i must say thanks.

Comment: +1 for `Stopwatch`; offers much better resolutions than `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a `float` problem; it's an `int` problem. You need to cast `err` to `double` before dividing it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Error: " + 100 * ((double)err / c) + "%");
```

Comment: Don't worry about it. Doh errors are part of the discipline. We've all done several.